# SQL: Must declare scalar variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

When I run the following T-SQL in SQL Server 2012 it works fine, but in SQL Server 2008 R2 I get the error

> Must declare the scalar variable "@in"`and`Must declare the scalar variable "@out"

Code:

```
DECLARE @outIds nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @in TimeLineReportList;
DECLARE @out TimeLineReportList;
DECLARE @startDate datetime;
DECLARE @endDate datetime;
DECLARE @assessmentId int;

SET @startDate ='2013-01-01T00:00:00.000'
SET @endDate ='2013-01-01T00:00:00.000'
SET @assessmentId = 14
SET @outIds ='3,9,10'

INSERT INTO @in
   SELECT * 
   FROM dbo.udf_First_Timeline_Entries_Of_Status(@assessmentId)

INSERT INTO @out
   SELECT * 
   FROM dbo.udf_First_Timeline_Entries_Of_Any_Statuses(@outIds)

SELECT * 
FROM dbo.udf_Generic_Timelines(@startDate, @endDate, @in, @out,default)
```

`TimeLineReportList` is a user-defined table type that definitely exists in the DB

**EDIT** I've just tested the first two queries by just running the following and both return results:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.udf_First_Timeline_Entries_Of_Status(@assessmentId)
SELECT * FROM dbo.udf_First_Timeline_Entries_Of_Any_Statuses(@outIds)
```

Comment: Is your database in 80 compatibility mode? Are these UDFs TVFs? Also 2008 <> 2008 R2.

Comment: @AaronBertrand definately 2008R2, not 2008. The 2012 instance is in 90 compatibility mode but the 2008R2 instance in 80

Comment: @AaronBertrand Oh an yes it is Table Valued Functions

Comment: I suspect the problem is compatibility mode - though I haven't verified this exact limitation. If you can confirm this syntax error goes away when switching to 90, say, I'll [update this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44908/what-is-the-actual-behavior-of-compatibility-level-80/44912#44912). (Why are you in 80 anyway?)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Not sure, it's an old system that I just recently took over. Might there be any specific reason why the DB was in 80 in the first place?

Comment: Lots of reasons, and these are not meant as derogatory: (1) laziness (you do have to test the change and perhaps make code changes) (2) ignorance (if you migrate a DB from 2000 -> 2008 R2, it just stays in 80 unless someone knows to change it) (3) fear (4) knowledge that code exists that will break on newer compat levels.

Comment: Thanks @AaronBertrand, that's very helpful. One more question though, if I change the compatibility mode now and there was actually a reason for it being in that mode, is it as simple as switching back?

Comment: Yes, you can switch back and forth no problem.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yup, that did the trick. Put it in an answer so I can mark it.

Comment: I'd rather move it to dba.se and close it as a duplicate of [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44908/what-is-the-actual-behavior-of-compatibility-level-80/44912#44912), which I updated to account for this scenario.

Comment: I agree it fits into dba.se, but the specifics of the error message will be lost by merging it into that answer which detracts from the searchability of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As detailed by comment from Aaron Bertrand, The issue is due to the compatibility mode of the database. Changing the compatibility to 90 (`SQL Server 2005`) fixed the issue. Newer features like UDT are not supported in databases with compatibility mode 80 (`SQL Server 2000`).

For more details on the effects and behavior of compatibility mode, refer to this thread [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44908/what-is-the-actual-behavior-of-compatibility-level-80).